# Opencv cannot find image file under visual studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, imread

I try to use opencv in visual stduio. I arrange integration steps visual studio and opencv.

I put an image under visual studio c++ project folder(same location vc++ project file not sln) . `imread` cannot find it. I use below code to upload an image :

```
cv::Mat target;
if (!(target = cv::imread("target.png", 1)).data) {
        std::cout << "File cannot open\n";
        return -1;
}
```

How can I load an image using imread on vs2013?

Comment: 1) avoid condensing like that, at least for clarity: `Mat target = imread(...); if(!target.data) {...}`. 2) Have you tried with full path (remember to escape slashes using `\\`, or `/`)?

Comment: sorry.. using "\\" or "/"

Comment: copy your image to destination folder (the folder where your exe is generate) then try again.

Comment: @Derman if he uses the Visual Studio Debugger he has to set the relative path of where the .exe is executed to the corresponding folder, otherwise your method won't work (probably that's the reason for the problem anyways)

Comment: @zumma in Visual Studio set the working directory of your debugger/application to the folder where your image (and/or the exe) is present by setting something like ProjectProperties->General->Debugger->"working directory" or use absolute pathes as Miki said.

Comment: @Miki I tried full path, it didin't work.

Comment: ehm... are you sure the path is correct ("\\" or "/")? the image exists? etc? If you can't load with full path then there's something else going on.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The project is an empty vs project. I create a new c++ project(but not empty), imread works in it.